# The length of the obj is 1 - javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to auto fill the city and state values based on the zip code inserted by the user. I'm unable to compare the entered zip code with the zip available in json object. The value of obj length is 1 , which must be 3.

```
var text = '{"zipcodes":[' +
'{"zip":"22031","city":"Fairfax" ,"State":"VA" },' +
'{"zip":"22032","city":"AshBurn" ,"State":"VA" },' +
'{"zip":"22033","city":"Tysons" ,"State":"VA" }]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var n = Object.keys(obj).length;

for(i=0; i<=n; i++){

    if(obj.zipcodes[i].zip.parseInt() == zipcodes.parseInt()){

        document.getElementById("city").value = obj.zipcodes[i].city;
        document.getElementById("state").value = obj.zipcodes[i].State;

    }
}
```

Comment: There's only one key in `obj`, `obj.zipcodes`, which is an array, which you'd loop with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The object after parsing becomes:

```
{
  "zipcodes":[
    {"zip":"22031","city":"Fairfax" ,"State":"VA" },
    {"zip":"22032","city":"AshBurn" ,"State":"VA" },
    {"zip":"22033","city":"Tysons" ,"State":"VA" }]}
  ]
};
```

So the key count of object is 1 which is zipcodes. If you want count of zipcodes,

Use this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var n = obj.zipcodes.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried the code, but looks like u really just got 1 key for the object, which is 'zipcodes'.

I think u should do loop through obj['zipcodes'] instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will indeed be of length 1. 
If you want to iterate through zip codes then for the given snippet above I would just do this:

```
var n = obj.zipcodes.length;
//continue your computation here.
```